# Amazon Linux AMI Apache User and Permission Web Directory

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, file-permissions, web-access

I have a AWS ec2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI running. As the web server I installed Apache and the web directory is `/var/www/html`.

Until now I had the permission for `/var/www/html` set as `777` under the **`user c2-user`** (`chmod -R 777 /var/www/html`).
I read, that you should usually have set the 644 permission for web access. But as soon as I do that, I get the **`403 forbidden`** error message. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between '7' and '6' is the *execute* bit. That's important on directories because it allows other users to enter the directory. Since the dir is opened by `ec2-user` and Apache runs as another user, the third number (of `777`) comes into play.

On individual files it may be okay to use permissions of `644`, as that prevents other users from being able to modify the file. This isn't always true, though- executable files need the executable bit and logs need to be writeable by their process.

Here's a quick overview on directories and unix permissions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opene

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Here I also found a good guide: http://www.sofer.com/research/unix.html